# Share pandas.DataFrame between Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, dataframe, tcp, lan

Our company has an API for Windows only(server), I've wrote some python code to convert raw data to pd.DataFrame on server. I hope to send this dataframe to another python program running on CentOS 7(client). I would be grateful if anyone could give me a solution.

According to my research, I built a socket server on Windows. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Date | Ticker1 | Ticker 2|
--------------------------
May11| 100.01  | 143.12  |
```

Here is my code on server:

```
records_to_send=df.to_records().tostring()
conn.send(records_to_send)
```

But when it comes to decoding, np.frombuffer() can't recognize the dtype I set. Even if I just run the following code on server:

```
np.frombuffer(df.to_records().to_string(),df.to_records().dtype)
```

would raise a ValueError:

```
ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer
```

Comment: Have you tried serializing to/from json?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: @clockwatcher Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas provides methods to serialize to json.  Use a dataframe's [to_json](http://%20http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method to serialize to json and pandas' [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) method to read that back into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
serialized=df.to_json()
print(serialized)
deserialized=pd.read_json(serialized)
print(deserialized)
```